# Translating native API into C#, Marshalling structs arrays and delegates

Tags: c#, arrays, interop, delegates, marshalling

I've worked on a C# version of a C++ API but I can't manage to get it right.

Since the whole API was too big the first time I posted, I've cut it down to some core functions for which I really need some help to make a managed version of.

So basically, this is a C++ dll containing exported functions that are used to communicate with a technical analysis software.

**C++ function I'd like to convert**

```
#define PLUGINAPI extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

PLUGINAPI int GetFunctionTable( FunctionTag **ppFunctionTable )
{
    *ppFunctionTable = gFunctionTable;
    // must return the number of functions in the table
    return gFunctionTableSize;
}
```

GetFunctionTable is called by the software which provides a pointer to an array of FunctionTag called gFunctionTable:

```
typedef struct FunctionTag
{
    char *Name;
    FunDesc  Descript;
} FunctionTag;

FunctionTag gFunctionTable[] = {"ExampleA",{ VExampleA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL },
                             "ExampleB",{ VExampleB, 1, 0, 1, 0, NULL }
                                 };
```

FunctionTag structure contains an embedded structure called Fundesc:

```
// FunDesc structure holds the pointer to actual
// user-defined function that can be called by AmiBroker.
typedef struct FunDesc
{
    AmiVar (*Function)( int NumArgs, AmiVar *ArgsTable );
    UBYTE   ArrayQty;       // number of Array arguments required   
    UBYTE   StringQty;      // number of String arguments required
    SBYTE   FloatQty;       // number of float args 
    UBYTE   DefaultQty;     // number of default float args
    float   *DefaultValues; // the pointer to defaults table 
} FunDesc;
```

Finally, Fundesc contains AmiVar type:

```
#pragma pack( push, 2 )
typedef struct AmiVar
{
    int type;
    union 
    {
        float   val;
        float   *array;
        char    *string;
        void *disp;
    };
} AmiVar;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

**C# conversion so far**

Now, this is what I've written so far in an attempt to get my C# dll to "mimic" the C++ original API. The GetFunctionTable() exported function:

```
namespace AmiBrokerFrontDll
{
   internal static class AmiBrokerFrontDll
   {

   [DllExport("GetFunctionTable", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
   public static Int32 GetFunctionTable(ref FunctionTag[] ppFunctionTable)
   {
       FillFunction();
       ppFunctionTable=gFunctionTable;
       return gFunctionTableSize;
   }
```

Then comes the definition of FunctionTag structure and gFunctionTableSize:

```
   [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
   public struct FunctionTag
   {
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
       public string Name;
       public FunDesc Description;
   }

   public static FunctionTag[] gFunctionTable=new FunctionTag[1];
   public static FunctionTag gfunc;
   static Int32 gFunctionTableSize = Marshal.SizeOf(gFunctionTable) / Marshal.SizeOf(gfunc);
   public static void FillFunction()
   {
        gFunctionTable[0].Name = "VExempleA";
        gFunctionTable[0].Description.Function += VExempleDeMacd;
        //ArrayQty, StringQty, FloatQty, DefaultQty, DefaultTablePtr
        gFunctionTable[0].Description.ArrayQty = 0;
        gFunctionTable[0].Description.StringQty = 0;
        gFunctionTable[0].Description.FloatQty = 2;
        gFunctionTable[0].Description.DefaultQty = 0;
        gFunctionTable[0].Description.DefaultValues = new IntPtr();
   }
```

FunDesc declaration includes a delegate:

```
   [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
   public delegate AmiVar FunctionDelegate(int NumArgs, ref AmiVar ArgsTable);

   public struct FunDesc
   {
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
       public FunctionDelegate Function;
       public byte ArrayQty; // The number of Array arguments required
       public byte StringQty; // The number of String arguments required
       public byte FloatQty; // The number of float args
       public byte DefaultQty; // The number of default float args
       public IntPtr DefaultValues; // The pointer to defaults table
   }
```

Finally, we have an AmiVar structure:

```
   [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 8)]
   public struct AmiVar
   {
       [FieldOffset(0)]
       public Int32 type;
       [FieldOffset(4)]
       public Single val;
       [FieldOffset(4)]
       public IntPtr array;
       [FieldOffset(4)]
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
       public string name;
       [FieldOffset(4)]
       public IntPtr disp;
   }
```

Sorry this is too long. Unfortunately, I couldn't make a small consise question. 
So this code compiled (maybe not anymore since this is an extract from the bigger picture) but when loading the resulting dll from the technical analysis software, I received an ACCESS VIOLATION ERROR. I believe this means the C# conversion doesn't map the C++ variables size correctly. With the arrays of structures and delegates this project has become too difficult for me to solve alone.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Guillaume

Comment: please cut this down. who's going to want to read all this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you want to "mimic" a C++ API in C#? do you mean you want to simpky use the existing C++ API with C#?

Comment: No, I don't want to use the existing API because it is in C++ and I don't understand this language. Basically, it's an application that loads the dll and through 5 standards functions, communicate with the dll passing function and variable pointers. GetFunctionTable() is one of them. The point of making a C# version that would be recognised by the application like the C++ one is, is for me to easily extend the dll and consequently the application features, such as adding a GUI interface, extract and analysis data from the appli before publishing on a web site etc.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help in your specific case, but I can tell you a couple things that will make your life easier:

1. Function pointers created from managed delegates should never, ever, ever, be stored in unmanaged code.  I don't say this lightly.  There are claims that if you create a function pointer from a delegate with [GetFunctionPointerForDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getfunctionpointerfordelegate.aspx), that the appropriate thunks will get created and won't ever get garbage collected.  This is **NOT** true.  I have watched function pointers that were good on one call go sour on the next.  The safest bet is to guarantee that function pointers will never get stored beyond the use of an unmanaged call.
2. P/Invoke is OK for some tasks, but by far the easiest way to integrate a non-C#-friendly C++ library is to make a better/more appropriate wrapper for it in C++/CLI.  See [here](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/stevehawley/archive/2008/07/02/how-to-build-a-managed-unmanaged-library.aspx) for a description of one way to approach the problem.